# Кэш страницы из переменной

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть код который кэширует страницу и сохраняет html файл

```
<?php
/* Установка кодироок в UTF-8 */
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");  // установим внутреннюю кодировку скрипта
mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );  // устанавливаем кодировку для http-вывода

//settings
$cache_ext  = '.html'; //file extension
$cache_time     = 1800;  //Cache file expires after these seconds (1 hour = 3600 sec) (8 hour = 28800 sec) (12 hour = 43200 sec)
$cache_folder   = 'cache/'; //folder to store Cache files
$ignore_pages   = array('', '');

$dynamic_url    = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // requested dynamic page (full url)
$cache_file     = $cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$cache_ext; // construct a cache file
$ignore = (in_array($dynamic_url,$ignore_pages))?true:false; //check if url is in ignore list

if (!$ignore && file_exists($cache_file) && time() - $cache_time < filemtime($cache_file)) { //check Cache exist and it's not expired.
ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); //Turn on output buffering, "ob_gzhandler" for the compressed page with gzip.
readfile($cache_file); //read Cache file
echo '<!-- cached page - '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', filemtime($cache_file)).', Page : '.$dynamic_url.' -->';
ob_end_flush(); //Flush and turn off output buffering
exit(); //no need to proceed further, exit the flow.
}
//Turn on output buffering with gzip compression.
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
?>
```

**страница**   echo $post;

```
<?php
######## Your Website Content Ends here #########

if (!is_dir($cache_folder)) { //create a new folder if we need to
mkdir($cache_folder);
}
if(!$ignore){
$fp = fopen($cache_file, 'w');  //open file for writing
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); //write contents of the output buffer in Cache file
fclose($fp); //Close file pointer
}
ob_end_flush(); //Flush and turn off output buffering

?>
```

Как вместо "страница" кэшировать переменную echo $post; ?

Т.е. в скрипте тело страницы не выводится, вместо кода страницы - $post;

Спасибо!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Мне нужно код страницы сохранить, которая выводится с помощью $post, я не понял при чем тут server   :(

Comment: `$_SERVER['post_cache'] = $post;`

Comment: Корвин, спасибо!

Comment: Из-за чего-то файл (не все) сохраняются в кэш в кодировке ANSI Windows-1251, на сервере читаемые а на сайте иероглифы. Как исправить? Спасибо!